# Update table with random record in update statment in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. `Table 1` has about 80 rows and `Table 2` has about 10 million.

I would like to update all the rows in `Table 2` with a random row from `Table 1`. I don't want the same row for all the rows. Is it possible to update `Table 2` and have it randomly select a value for each row it is updating?

This is what I have tried, but it puts the same value in each row.

```
update member_info_test
set hostessid = (SELECT TOP 1 hostessId FROM hostess_test ORDER BY NEWID())
```

**Edited

Comment: This will point you in the right direction : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

Comment: You don't want the same record for one? Difficult when the first table has 80 and the table you want to update has 10M records.

Comment: Well not all the same records for every record. I just want it to use the 80 records from that one table

Comment: Do you need to do an update?  Can you just remove all records and do an insert?

Comment: Your query looks okay.  The only thing I can think of is that the optimizer is executing the subquery only once.  It should not be doing so, because `newid()` is volatile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I think that this is one of the weirdest query that I've wrote, and I think that this is gonna be terrible slow. But give it a shot:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.hostessid = B.hostessId
FROM member_info_test A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 hostessId
             FROM hostess_test 
             WHERE A.somecolumn = A.somecolumn
             ORDER BY NEWID()) B
```

Comment: The values are all the same :(

Comment: @chobo - Really?, I tested this with sample data and it worked fine. But to get the different values, the `WHERE A.somecolumn = A.somecolumn` was mandatory

Comment: I don't know why it works for you, but I get the same values in each row

Comment: Actually this query sort of works, but what confuses me is the Where A.somecolumn = A.somecolumn. I seem to get different results depending on the columns I use

Comment: It seems the more different values A.someColumn has the more random the results

Comment: @chobo that may be the reason. I tried it with the key for that table and it worked as intended.

Comment: You would need to correlate on a unique value from `A` to be sure that if a spool is added it is always rebound not rewound. [Duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12922951/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith I did that on my test query, but not knowing that it was a necessity. And your answer explains why it works that way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work (at least, the `with` portion does):

```
with toupdate as (
      select (select top . . . hostessId from hostess_test where mit.hostessId = mit.hostessId order by newid()) as newval,
             mit.*
      from member_info_test mit
     )
update toupdate
    set hostessid = newval;
```

The key to this (and to Lamak's) is the outer correlation in the subquery. This is convincing the optimizer to actually run the query for each row. I don't know why this would work and the other version would not.

Comment: If you put in a 1 where the `. . .` is, then it should work.  Any idea why I cannot insert this code?

Comment: This worked fine for me in SQL2012; I had to omit the `mit` alias in the `update` portion, however.  All-in-all, a good, logical, solution for a one-off problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i ended up using:

EnvelopeInformation would be your Table 2

PaymentAccountDropDown  would be your Table 1  (in my case i had 3 items) - change 3 to 80 for your usecase.

```
;WITH cteTable1 AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS n,
        PaymentAccountDropDown_Id
    FROM EnvelopeInformation
    ),
cteTable2 AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS n,
        t21.Id
    FROM PaymentAccountDropDown t21
    )
UPDATE cteTable1
   SET PaymentAccountDropDown_Id = (
       SELECT Id 
       FROM cteTable2
       WHERE  (cteTable1.n % 3) + 1 = cteTable2.n
)
```

reference: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/f58c3bf8-e6b7-4cf5-9466-7027164afdc0/updating-multiple-rows-with-random-values-from-another-table

Answer (score 0):

[Update Table with Random fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484933/update-records-with-random-fields)

```
UPDATE p
    SET p.City= b.City
    FROM Person p
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 City
                 FROM z.CityStateZip 
                 WHERE p.SomeKey = p.SomeKey and -- ... the magic! ↓↓↓
                 Id = (Select ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % (Select count(*) from z.CityStateZip)))) b
```