# Update Table with Random fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a "data obfuscator" script. I want to update every record in a table with fake data. I have a table with locations and trying to select a random record from that table to update the records in my person table. So SQL similiar to this

```
UPDATE Person
SET    City = (SELECT TOP 1 City
               FROM   z.CityStateZip c2
               ORDER  BY Newid())
```

The problem with this is that it only ever selects 1 city, instead of selecting a random City for each person. I've also tried

```
(SELECT TOP 1 City FROM z.CityStateZip c2 ORDER BY NEWID()), PersonId, from Person
```

But it still only selects 1 city (I thought sub queries ran once for every record) instead of what I desire -- a random city for each record.

I've also tried doing a join with the same results, only 1 city ever selected....

```
SELECT t.City,
       PersonId
FROM   Person
       INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 City
                   FROM   z.CityStateZip c2
                   ORDER  BY Newid()) t
               ON 1 = 1
```

I tried to shove this statement into a function but SQL Server doesn't allow me to use `NEWID()` inside a function.

**Answer**

I modified Giorgi's answer and the answer to the linked question and came up with this, it is very fast! I changed how I was randomly selecting a city. The order by NewId() was an issue. So Person has 5k records and CityStateZip has ~30K, I took it down from 40 seconds to 4...(now even faster without the count subquery)

```
DECLARE @count bigint 
SELECT @count = count(*) from z.CityStateZip

UPDATE p
SET p.City= b.City
FROM Person p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 City -- if Id is unique, top 1 shouldn't be necessary
             FROM z.CityStateZip 
             WHERE p.SomeKey = p.SomeKey and -- ... the magic! ↓↓↓
             Id = (Select ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % @count))) b
```

Comment: Instead of a subselect, try JOINing to a derived table.

Comment: @Tab, I also tried that with no luck.

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks for that link. This does appear to be a duplicate. My google skills have failed me.

Comment: Even though its a duplicate still its a worthy one

Comment: That's okay, happened to me quite a few times too. I had already upvoted your question. Well-asked duplicates serve a purpose: others that use *your* terminology too will land here after searching, and thus find the dupe with answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should force the database engine to evaluate new value for each row. You can do this by adding dummy where clause on outer table like:

```
DECLARE @city TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), City VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @city VALUES
('Dallas'),
('New York'),
('Washington'),
('Las Vegas')


DECLARE @random TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), City VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @random VALUES
('Manchester'),
('London'),
('Oxford'),
('Liverpool')


SELECT * FROM @city c
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @random r WHERE c.ID = c.ID ORDER BY NEWID()) ca
```

if you remove `WHERE c.ID = c.ID` you will get same value for all rows.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi, I was able to get this to work, along with the answer from the dup question. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? The cross apply and NEWID() is pretty slow. I guess I could use TableSample but that doesn't give me truly random results.

Comment: check out my edit, I was able to increase speed by a couple orders of magnitude